# Reskit on iOS unable to get gzip content

Tags: ios, web-services, rest, gzip, restkit

I've a rest GET webservice I call in my application, which return gzip content.
But I'm unable to get a correct return.

I always got the `"-1015 error: cannot decode raw data"`.

In my code, I tried:

```
[[objectManager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"Accept-Encoding" value:@"gzip, deflate"];
```

Restkit version is 0.20.3.

Thank you for your help.